# google contacts API is not working

Tags: c#, google-api, google-contacts-api

Hi I used below code to get google contacts data, since 31st March google announced requests to their api should use [https](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/http-update) and therefore it gives "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/fullMovedPermanently" error, but when we call api we don't set any url and we cannot change url from http to https, anyone has any idea please?

```
 RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings("API Project", "username", "password");
                rs.AutoPaging = true;
                ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);
                Feed<Contact> feeds = cr.GetContacts();
                foreach (Contact gContact in feeds.Entries)
                {
                    MMS.Model.Contacts.Contact contact = new MMS.Model.Contacts.Contact() { MailAccountId = mailAccount.MailAccountId };
                    contact.Email = gContact.PrimaryEmail.Address;
                    contact.FirstName = gContact.Title.Split(' ')[0].ToString();
                    if (gContact.Title.Split(' ').Count() > 1)
                        contact.LastName = gContact.Title.Split(' ')[1].ToString();
                    if (!contactRepo.ContactExist(contact))
                        contactRepo.Save(contact);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [New Google Api Pack](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/detail?name=Google_Data_API_Setup_2.2.0.0.msi). Replace new dll on your bin folder

Comment: this API pack does not have Google.GData.Contacts.dll file

Answer (score 0):

You have to authorize your application with oauth2.

see https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

Set the ContactId to https instead of http.
Like this:

> https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/joe.bloggs%40domain.com/base/some_id